# Transparent ListBox or Listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I want set Listbox background to transparent but not working
Is there any idea?

Comment: is it Windows app or web app?

Comment: ListBox.BackColor=Color.Transparent
or any thing like this!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exemple with label is a good idea if you don't want to use WPF. But, if you want to sort, the list a purpose to you to create a list with all the label name and create the number of label you need in a flowpanel. When you want to sort, you not sort the label, but the list, and after change the name of the label.

Ju

Answer (score 2):

As you've no doubt encountered it appears that you can't do this with a ListBox. One possible alternative ([suggested here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_22523298.html)) is to use a list of Labels (which can be transparent) in place of a ListBox. It might not be practical for your situation but it's an option.

Comment: Sorry but I have not www.experts-exchange.com account

Comment: Neither do I emdadgar2. The answers are there they're just hard to get at. I think they hide them unless you're coming from Google. Try going here http://www.google.ie/search?q=%22Transparent+Listview%22+site%3Awww.experts-exchange.com, click on the first search item found and then scroll down a few pages to get to the answers.

Comment: Thanks but I tried it before and not working (very slow).

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use Windows presentation foundation ! (WPF)